# deploy CRD resource using make deploy command in terraform

Tags: kubernetes, makefile

I am currently seeking assistance with deploying a CRD (Custom Resource Definition) resource using the "make deploy IMG=myrepository" command. I would greatly appreciate any insights or ideas on how to achieve this using Terraform.

Thank you in advance for your help!

getting below error while doing provisioner "local-exec"

Output: 'make' is not recognized as an internal or
│ external command,

Comment: Can you include some code examples of how you are trying to achieve this? Also - do you have a makefile that you can copy in? Any specific reason as to why you need make and not just run `kubectl apply` under your local-exec?

Comment: Hi Alex ,

To deploy the neo4j operator with CRD,  Inside the directory, I have all the CRD files and your Neo4j image is located inside your private repository. Now, I want to run the following command : make deploy IMG=ng-postgres-operator:v1

Comment: Well, that error message is being printed by the Windows `cmd.exe` shell.  My suspicion is that whatever instructions you are following expect you to be running on a POSIX system like Linux.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.